# How to solve 'Value of type 'DJIVideoFeed' has no member 'remoteCamera'' error when trying to do real-time object detection with DJI Drone?

Tags: swift, coreml, dji-sdk, drone.io

I am trying to do real time object detection with DJI Drone. I want to combine the AVCaptureVideo command and the DJISDK video process and show the image and object detection frames on a single layer view.

This is the setupCapture function:

```
func setupCapture() {
    let fpvWidget = DUXBetaFPVWidget()
    fpvWidget.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    addChild(fpvWidget)
    fpvWidget.didMove(toParent: self)
    previewView.addSubview(fpvWidget.view)
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        fpvWidget.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: previewView.leadingAnchor),
        fpvWidget.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: previewView.trailingAnchor),
        fpvWidget.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: previewView.topAnchor),
        fpvWidget.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: previewView.bottomAnchor)
    ])
                
    guard let videoCaptureDevice = DJISDKManager.videoFeeder()?.primaryVideoFeed.remoteCamera?.videoCaptureDevice else {
        print("Failed to get DJI video capture device")
        return
    }
            
    do {
        let videoCaptureInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoCaptureDevice)
        
        if captureSession.canAddInput(videoCaptureInput) {
            captureSession.addInput(videoCaptureInput)
        } else {
            print("Failed to add video capture input to capture session")
            return
        }
    }
}
```

I am using captureSession in this func:

```
//MARK: SetupLayers
func setupLayers() {
    previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
    previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
    rootLayer = previewView.layer
    previewLayer.frame = rootLayer.bounds
    rootLayer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
   .
   .
   .
```

But I get the following error from DJI SDK:

> Value of type 'DJIVideoFeed' has no member 'remoteCamera' for this code:

```
DJISDKManager.videoFeeder()?.primaryVideoFeed.remoteCamera?.videoCaptureDevice else
```

I also tried:

```
guard let videoCaptureDevice = DJISDKManager.videoFeeder()?.primaryVideoFeed.physicalSource else {
    print("Failed to get DJI video capture device")
    return
}
```

But then I get this error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'DJIVideoFeedPhysicalSource' to expected argument type 'AVCaptureDevice'

for this code:

```
let videoCaptureInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoCaptureDevice)
```

What should I do?